# Why does this give me an attribute error?

Tags: python, adventure

I'm working on a text-based adventure game, and this code searches through a room file and pulls a substring from it that adds it to a list of enemies.

```
with y.index("~") as _0:
    self.room_enemies.append(y[_0:_0])
    print(y[_0:_0])
```

However, when I run it, it gives me this:

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

If this isn't enough information for a good answer, please let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. I get [a totally different error](https://replit.com/@codeguru/GoldenrodTemporalDisassembly#main.py) when I run your code.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `with y.index("~") as _0:`, *what do you expect this to mean*? Why?

Comment: Aside from that problem, what do you expect y[_0:_0] to do? How many elements do you think will be in the result? Why? (Answer: it will give an empty list, no matter what `y` contains.)

Comment: `with` is used to make a context manager, which requires that the object in question have special methods such as `__enter__`.  Your object does not have these methods.

Comment: I expected it to work as a temporary variable, as if renaming `y.index("~")` to `_0` for that small section of the code.

Comment: Please also see [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) - not also a duplicate, but important background information for your task.

Comment: @DominicMiller Check out the link at the top of your question for an explanation of how with works. To do what you want, use regular assignment: `_0 = y.index("~")`. And then you'll need to figure out if `y[_0:_0]` does what you think it does.

Comment: _I expected it to work as a temporary variable_ Why would you expect that?  Is there some documentation stating it works that way?

Answer (score 3):

`with` is not variable assignment. If you want to assign variables, use the equal sign.

```
_0 = y.index("~")
```

(Though `_0` is an extremely bizarre variable name)

`with` is used with [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), such as opened files or database connections, and it's sort of like Java's try-with-resources block. It won't work on arbitrary data types that haven't been designed with the construct in mind.

Comment: It's not unreasonable that they might assume that `with` is for creating a block-scoped variable, like Lisp's `let`.